# Search and replace in MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I have a mongo collection that contains a field called "url", storing an url.
Some of those urls have an extra parameter that bothers me, "id=<>" where <> can have any size
Can i do this in a update operation or do i need to write a script that will iterate and replace?

```
db.find({{"url": /.&id=.*/ }}).update(???)
```

Comment: does any size(<>) means: "http:website.com_id=<sf4534df>" as eg?. give some sample example

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be to explore use of the "multi" parameter in conjunction with field update parameters, as described at these locations on the MongDB website.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter

An example is provided here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-multi

The issue is that you won't be able to implement any sort of "capturing group" functionality that just gets rid of the "id" parameter for each document though. There is a ticket open on MongoDB's jira account though detailing this behavior (currently in unresolved state):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9159

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find documents using this regEx and then do update accordingly.

```
db.find({
    "url": /id=\<.+\>/
}, function(err, result) {
    //your code
})
```